# AttributeError: 'AlumniResponseFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'new_objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using the Django admin and trying to make some changes to a related object that is mapped as an [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin) object.  I'm trying to do this using the [save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) method that Django provides.   When I try to save something, I get an error:

`AttributeError: 'AlumniResponseFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'new_objects'`

#### Other Info:

1) I have two InlineModelAdmins
2) I'm not saving the AlumniResponseInline when this error occurs.  I'm saving another InlineModelAdmin associated with the same parent model
3) Until I added the save_related() method, I wasn't having problems saving either InlineModelAdmin
4) This error is happening after all *my* code is executed in save_related(), so I don't have control over catching that exception

From the documentation on [save_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related):

> The save_related method is given the HttpRequest, the parent ModelForm instance, the list of inline formsets and a boolean value based on whether the parent is being added or changed. Here you can do any pre- or post-save operations for objects related to the parent. Note that at this point the parent object and its form have already been saved.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? struggling with same issue.

Comment: @ValAyal that is a dead link now.

Comment: Hmm, yep. I removed it.  No idea what that was pointing to or why it was useful back then.

Answer (score 9):

I use *save_formset* instead of *save_related* and I was having the same problem until I realized that I missed two important lines inside the method:

```
instances = formset.save(commit=False)
```

at the beginning, and then, after loop instances to do something with each instance:

```
instance.save() #commit instance changes
formset.save_m2m() #commit the whole formset changes
```

at the end.

If you don't call the save_m2m() method before return, the formset object won't have the 'new_objects' attribute, needed in the `construct_change_message(self, request, form, formsets)` method in contrib/admin/options.py

So, this should be done for every inline you have in the main model, no matter whether you want to make something with it or not.